# so , why is this fetch function called in the server component not invioking the fetch GET function in the route handler file

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

so , i am just practicing next js 13.4 new experimantal app feature with the react server component ....
long story short i have a program which chnages a markdown files for blog articles and i do that with the node js and gray-matter by reading the file ..

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import matter from 'gray-matter'

const postsdir = path.join(process.cwd(),'src','data','Posts')

async function getPostData(filename) {
    const filePath = path.join(postsdir, filename)
    const postInfo = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf-8')
    const postSlugName = filename.replace(/\.md$/,'')
    const { data, content } = matter(postInfo)
    const PostData = {
        slug: postSlugName,
        data: data, 
        content:content
    }
    return PostData
}

export async function getAllPosts() {
    const Posts = fs.readdirSync(postsdir)
    const AllPostsData = await Promise.all(Posts.map(async (post) => {
        return await getPostData(post)
    }))
    return AllPostsData.sort((postA, postB) => postA.date > postB.date ? -1 : 1)
}

export async function getFeaturedPosts(){
    const allPosts = await getAllPosts()
    const featuredPosts = allPosts.filter(post => post.data.isFeatured === true)
    return featuredPosts
}
```

and i know that nde js cannot used in the client side so to call the function to get the posts i will require to have a server component , which is what next js 13.4 new thing is about . so i have a api route handler to get featured post which is contained in the head of the markdown file as boolean(isFeatured) ..

```
import { getFeaturedPosts } from "@/lib/PostsGateway";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {
    console.log('get method run')
    const featuredPosts = await getFeaturedPosts()
    console.log(featuredPosts)
    return NextResponse.json(featuredPosts)
}
```

this is just a simple api route handler for the get request from fetch ... it is inside src/app/api/featuredPosts ..
then the way of invoking the get function is by making a default fetch request which is a get request ..

```
import Hero from "@/components/Home/Hero"
import FeaturedPosts from "@/components/Home/featuredPosts";
import { getFeaturedPosts } from "@/lib/PostsGateway";

async function getData() {
  "use server"
  const fPosts = await fetch('http://localhost/api/featuredPosts')
  return fPosts
}

export default async function HomePage() {
  const featuredPosts = await getData()
  console.log(featuredPosts)
  return (
    <>
      <Hero />
      <FeaturedPosts posts={featuredPosts} />
    </>
  )
}
```

i want to fetch the markdown file info which is fetch through the fetch function in the getData() function which is a server component and with the fetch default function it should have invoked the get function in the api/festuredPosts route.js > GET() function , but i does not invoke , and the error says : fail to fetch and i dont know , i had used it in previous days , but that was with the client component now that it is a small blog kind of practice , there is no need to make it a client and i am useing node js which cannot run on client side ..

i was trying to get a markdown file in a object with slug , data and content which was developed by the matter from the gray-matter , but the error pops up with feiled fetch and when i use the fetch('/api/featuredPosts') then it says it cannot parse the url from 'api/featuredPosts' but i thought the way to call the api route handler was this but in the app i wrote "http:localhost/api/featuredPosts" as Bing Ai said to , but again nope ... plz see if there is something worng with my code and give suggestions
thank you

Answer (score 0):

As you're on a server component you're already on the server and don't need to be calling the API, you could just do `const featuredPosts = await getFeaturedPosts()` directly in the `HomePage` component like so:

```
export default async function HomePage() {
  const featuredPosts = await getFeaturedPosts()
  return (
    <>
      <Hero />
      <FeaturedPosts posts={featuredPosts} />
    </>
  )
}
```